# how to make a login first page to enter into the joomla based website?

Tags: joomla2.5

i am very beginner in web development and making my first project website. please help me i want to make a website in joomla 2.5. i want to use a login page to enter into the website because for the moment i want keep everything behind the door. only users with password will enter into the site.  i tried to search on the below link but could not succeed. 
http://docs.joomla.org/Screen.menus.edit.15#Internal_Link_-_User
please anyone help me.
alot of thanks in Advance)))

Answer (score 0):

you can get this working by setting up access level of all your menu items as registered. Except the one you want to use for login page.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend setting up access levels on your menu at this stage of building your site.

If all you're trying to achieve is that everyone has to have a username and password to get to the site, I would use folder security through your hosting control panel(CPANEL or PLESK probably).

Setting up Folder security here will mean users have to login to get to the site but the site can be built as if it were public.

Setting menu security in Joomla can lead to confusing beginner experience when items don't show and you can't figure out why.